# how do identify the actual exception while pod failure happens in aks cluster

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kubernetes, azure-aks, kestrel

I am using Ev2 to deploy my dotnetcore mvc app to aks cluster. The pod status is 'CrashLoopBackOff'. And when I look at the logs with kubectl I see some warnings but I don't see any exceptions at all. The application health link fails with 404. I believe it is able to enter startup file since the use kestrel thing is coming up in log but I would like to see where the failure which leads to application shutting down is happening. Any inputs will be massively helpful.

NOTE : There was a key which I have replaced with hidden-key while pasting here

```
C:\Users\jeevanm>kubectl logs  <pod-name> -n mynamespace
←[40m←[1m←[33mwarn←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
      Creating key {<hidden key>} with creation date 2020-10-29 02:59:54Z, activation date 2020-10-29 02:59:54Z, and expiration date 2021-01-27 02:59:54Z.
←[40m←[1m←[33mwarn←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {<hidden key>} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[39]
      Writing data to file '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys/key-<hidden-key>.xml'.
←[40m←[1m←[33mwarn←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'https://+:443'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:443
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://10.60.1.248:443/health
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 66.2889ms 404
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://10.60.1.248:443/health
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 2.0592ms 404
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://10.60.1.248:443/health
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 5.1835ms 404
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://10.60.1.248:443/health
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 2.2746ms 404
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://10.60.1.248:443/health
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1.4105ms 404
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://10.60.1.248:443/health
←[40m←[32minfo←[39m←[22m←[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 2.104ms 404
Application is shutting down...
```

Comment: Solution is to add a health url or disabled livenessProbe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1